# Fetch input value from certain class and send with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
<input id="u1" class="username">
<input id="u2" class="username">
<input id="u3" class="username">
...
```

How to fetch input value with "username" class and send with ajax jquery to php page.

i want to recive data like simple array or simple json. (i need INPUT values  and not ids)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var inputValues = [];
$('input.username').each(function() { inputValues.push($(this).val()); });

// Do whatever you want with the inputValues array
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = new Array();
$('.username').each(function(){
    values.push( $(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I find it best to use jQuery's built in [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method. It sends the form data just like a normal for submit would. You simply give jQuery the id of your form and it takes care of the rest. You can even grab the forms action if you would like.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: $("#your-form").serialize(),
  success: function(data){
    //alert response from server
    alert(data);
  }
});
```